# How to get top 5 repeated Regex.Matches in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I wanna build a program to crawl some websites, check for the style.css file, open it, and with a Regex which is `#([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])(?=;)` I want to get the top 5 colors of the style.css

If there are 200 colors in my regex result, I wanna get the top 5 meaning.

For example my regex will find this color #ffffff 100 times, which means this will be my first color.

The color #343434 will be found 98 times, this will be my second color.

And so on to get the top 5 colors from the style.css file.

Any ideas on how to implement this ?

I found this sort of example on here:

```
var l1 = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4,5,2,2,2,4,4,4,1 };

        var g = l1.GroupBy( i => i );

        foreach( var grp in g )
        {
           Console.WriteLine( "{0} {1}", grp.Key, grp.Count() );
        }
```

But it's not really what I'm looking for.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are 16777216 possible colors, so you'll have to maintain a 16777216 size table of how often each individual color occurs.

Comment: The algorithm is obvious. Build a color histogram (map color => count), sort by value, pick top five.

Comment: @MrLister not really. Most of the colors will never appear.

Comment: with the above example, I think it's possible to do it, but I don't know how to sort them.

Comment: @JanDvorak But this is a web crawler! So there are billions of webpages to crawl!

Comment: @MrLister yep, only few of them will appear, probably 100-200 colors, but I guess that's the maximum.

Comment: @user1812076 Wait, is the problem that you don't know how to sort?

Comment: @MrLister buddy, I am crawling only 2000 webpages, so I will do this for each page, I don't wanna get the top 5 colors from 2000 webpages, I wanna get the top for each webpage.

Comment: @user1812076 did you just reply to yourself _and notify yourself_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
var topMatches = Regex.Matches(stringToCheck, RegExPattern)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .GroupBy(m => m.Value)
    .Select(m => new{ Colour = m.Key, Count = m.Count() })
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count)
    .Take(5)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: `=>` creates a lambda expression (anonymous function)? I want that in JS :-)

Comment: Just did it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
var colors = l1.GroupBy(x => x)
                .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                .Select(g => g.Key)
                .Take(5)
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var g = <your matches>.
    GroupBy(i => i).
    OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count()).
    Take(5).
    Select(k => k.Key).
    ToList();
```